Is this a safe game to play with my kids?
I play with my kids "swords", they take a wooden ruler and I take nunchucks, I tell them that I am "Bruce Lee", I don't strike them and I just avoid their attack with my nunchucks, when they hit my hips, or my belly several times - I fall on the floor on my back, and the kids say: "daddy is dead..."

I don't see how it's not safe as long as you don't strike them back as you said (obviously). You can preferably use plastic/paper nunchucks to be absolutely sure that it won't harm them on accident. I think this is a good activity to do with your kids.

Though, I am not sure about the "daddy is dead" part. I mean, I'm not sure if I can explain it right but it just feels wrong to me if they know what death is. If you have told them to say that, I would suggest not to. It's just something creepy to say during an otherwise wholesome activity.

Hi Joe, I've closed this as basically a duplicate of your earlier one. I don't think it makes sense to ask a question re every game you come up with and ask if it is safe or good - that's not really what this site is for.
